# CASE statement in Oracle - depending on 2 columns (not 1) multiple

Tags: oracle, case, multiple-columns

I have such a table where I may have 
`TABLE_ITEM_DEFINITION`:

```
╔═════════════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║        Name         ║ Language ║ object_id ║
╠═════════════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ My Name in english  ║ en       ║ 123459098 ║
║ mon nom en espagnol ║ sp       ║ 123459098 ║
║ my name in Klingon  ║ kl       ║ 123459098 ║
╚═════════════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

when showing the object after my query: I intend to get the english name if it exists, otherwise spanish one if exists, otherwise klingon..I.E. I'll show only one name that exists first acc to my criteria.

Comment: And is there any grouping column that indicate that it is a name? Or your table has only 3 records and does not allow to place any other data like rank, birthplace, nation, ...

Comment: It links to the MAIN_OBJECT_TABLE over object_id.

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COALESCE` and self join:

```
SELECT m.*, COALESCE(t1.Name, t2.Name, t3.Name) AS result
FROM MAIN_OBJECT_TABLE m
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ITEM_DEFINITION t1
  ON m.object_id = t1.object_id
  AND t1.Language = 'en'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ITEM_DEFINITION t2
  ON m.object_id = t2.object_id
  AND t2.Language = 'sp'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_ITEM_DEFINITION t3
  ON m.object_id = t3.object_id
  AND t3.Language = 'kl'
WHERE m.object_id = 123459098;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424440)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation the best way is to improve your design first. Since you have a lot of objects with names in different languages, you should create a table for language priorities:

```
create table language_priority (
language_name  varchar2(2),
priority_level number);

insert into language_priority(language_name, priority_level) values ('en', 1);
insert into language_priority(language_name, priority_level) values ('sp', 2);
insert into language_priority(language_name, priority_level) values ('kl', 3);
```

Now you join this table with `TABLE_ITEM_DEFINITION` and select row with highest priority:

```
select name 
  from (select name, row_number() over (order by lp.priority_level) rn
          from TABLE_ITEM_DEFINITION tid,
               language_priority lp
         where lp.language_name = tid.language
           and tid.object_id = 123459098)
 where rn = 1
```

Also you can make "priority table" without of creating table, using `with` clause, but this solution is a sort of hardcode:

```
with language_priority as (
        select 'en' language_name, 1 priority_level union all
        select 'sp' language_name, 2 priority_level union all
        select 'kl' language_name, 3 priority_level)
select name 
  from (select name, row_number() over (order by lp.priority_level) rn
          from TABLE_ITEM_DEFINITION tid,
               language_priority lp
         where lp.language_name = tid.language
           and tid.object_id = 123459098)
 where rn = 1
```

Both solutions allow to easily add a lot of new languages and change their priorities.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, object_id, language
from (
  select name, object_id, language, 
         row_number() over (order by decode(language, 'en', 1, 'sp', 2, 3) as rn
  from table_item_definition
  where object_id = 123459098 
) t
where rn = 1;
```

If you need to join that to your `main_object_table` table you can do that like this:

```
select m.*, 
       ti.name, 
       ti.language
from main_object_table  m
  join (
    select name, object_id, language, 
           row_number() over (partition by object_id order by decode(language, 'en', 1, 'sp', 2, 3) as rn
    from table_item_definition
  ) ti on ti.object_id = m.object_id and ti.rn = 1
where m.object_id = 123459098;
```

If there might be no row at all in `table_item_definition` then you need to use an outer join (`left join`) instead of the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

```
select UNIQUE object_id, 
       FIRST_VALUE(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY object_id 
                      ORDER BY  (case when Language = 'en' then 1
                      when Language = 'sp' then 2
                       else 3 end))
       from TABLE_ITEM_DEFINITION
```